# equations for cuspidal curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The space of morphisms $\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^2$ of degree $3$ is a Zariski open subset $U$ of
$$
\mathbb P(H^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O(3))^{\oplus 3}) \cong \mathbb P^{11}
$$
the generic rational map is a nodal cubic, so the subset $V\subset U$ of cuspidal curves is of codimension at least $1$.

How can one find equations for $\overline{V}\subset \mathbb P^{11}$? I expect it to be a hypersurface but I cannot figure out how to write down the equation.

Comment: All cuspidal cubics are projectively equivalent to $V(y^2z-x^3)$ - maybe this will help? (It doesn't immediately give me the equations, though...)

Comment: @KReiser All nodal cubics are equivalent to $V(y^2z-x^2(x-1))$ also, so I don't really know how to use that

Comment: The tangent cone to the cusp is a double line, whereas the tangent cone to the node is a pair of transversely intersecting lines; does this description help?

Comment: @TabesBridges How can you identify from the coefficients of the rational map where the node is?

Comment: why was this question closed? That's silly.